# Formatting Footer with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am modifying a VBA code another person did at my work place. They have code inserting a footer into a generated quote form. The code for the footer is:

```vb
Frow = Sheets("Quote").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Row

Trow = Frow - 1
Hrow = Frow + 4
Srow = Frow + 4

Sheets("Quote").Range("F" & Frow).Value = "TOTAL:"
Sheets("Quote").Range("G" & Frow).Value = "=SUM(G13:G" & Trow & ")"

Sheets("Quote").Range("A" & Hrow).Value = Foot

'merge with next row
Range("A" & Hrow, "G" & Srow).Select
    
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = True
End With
```

It is moving the text from another sheet and pasting it on the newly generated quote sheet. The problem I am having is that text is very long and gets cut off. I have `WrapText` set to true as you can see, but the cell is not resizing to show the wrapped text.

What do I need to add to this to get it to autofit?
For reference, here is the beginning of the code where `Foot` is defined:

```vb
Sub CreateQuote1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim LastcRow, LastqRow
    Dim Dst
    Dim Foot
    Dim Frow, Trow, Hrow, Srow
    Dim c
    Dim cRange As Range
            
    LastcRow = Sheets("Data Entry").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    LastqRow = Sheets("Quote").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Foot = Sheets("Instructions").Range("A15").Value
```

I tried adding `With Selection` under `Foot`, but I could not get it to work, and I was unable to find the proper code for autofit in that format.

Comment: `What do I need to add to this to get it to autofit?` - call [`Autofit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofit)?

Comment: I read that particular document, but don't understand how to correctly implement it. The range on the cell will vary widely depending on the length of the quote that is being generated.

Comment: No, you need to have a single cell. E.g. you can always merge the cells of the entire row and then call Autofit to increase that row's height if necessary.

Comment: What would that look like? The last "operation" is to merge the cells. How would I then implement autofit?

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to a friend who knows code better than I, autofit does not work with this. The best course of action was to increase the amount of merged rows allowing for the text to be shown in its entirety.
He did so by changing the code to the following:

```
  Range("A" & Hrow, "G" & Srow + 5).Select
            
            With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = True
            End With
```

He added +5 to the sRow, increasing the amount of rows merged, solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

question, im not an expert but why dont you create the word template and in the footer add "rich text content control" those you can edit wit vba

```
wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TitleOfCC").Item(1).Range.Text = FormName.box1.Value
```

this is how i do when i have long texts, and with content control i change only the variable text

Comment: `why dont you create the word template` - because it's Excel?

Comment: to be easy, in my case the word template contain all the text and Content Controls where i expect text changes. i open the template end with accuracy i change only the content controls.

Comment: And if i want to add multiple lines in one content control i use something like this     ```
For x = 0 To 99
                temporary = temporary & cells(1, i) & vbCrLf
Next x 
```